# spring data solr showcase setting @SolrDocument(solrCoreName="...") from property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, solr

I am trying out the https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase

I am trying to make the code work in multiple different environments where the Solr core name could be different.  Using a property to specify the core name would seem like a useful way of doing this.

So I am trying to set the @SolrDocument(solrCoreName="...") from a property which I have added to the application.properties file like this:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = @Value("${solr.core}"))
public class Product implements SearchableProductDefinition {
    private @Id @Indexed String id;
    private @Indexed(NAME_FIELD_NAME) String name;
...
}
```

but I get a maven compilation error of:

```
.../git/spring-data-solr-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/showcase/product/model/Product.java:[31,30] annotation not valid for a value of type java.lang.String
```

I am new to Spring.  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not at the time @zakibenz. There is a JIRA improvement ticket to address the issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-304 Can you upvote it or contact Christoph Strobl (assignee) directly? It seems to be quite a popular request. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Should be working since DATASOLR-463: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/issues/582